# How do I change an EditText Property (on another activity) inside a class?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

My activity `signUpClient.kt` calls an API class, sending the EditText texts to the API (within a model called clients):

*signUpAPI.postClient(client)*

Inside this API, there's a function that posts client (code below).
Whenever the given email already exists, the server returns an error message. I can display the error via Toast, passing the correct context.

The thing is: I want to indicate to the user that the field `email` is incorrect, changing the property of it's EditText.

I tried to access it's ID from the API, but it doesn't access it.

Is there any way to doing this?

> *NOTE: I know how to change EditText properties, the problem is how to change it from another class (that's isn't even an activity).*
>   *I tried to use `findViewById` unsuccessfully.*

**signup_client.kt:**

```
   btn_signup.setOnClickListener() {

       val name = et_name.text.toString()
       val email = et_email.text.toString()
       val cellphone = et_cellphone.text.toString()
       val birthdate = et_birthdate.text.toString()
       val password = et_password.text.toString()


       // Constructs a new client object
       val client = Client(
           name,
           email,
           cellphone,
           birthdate,
           password
       )

       signUpAPI = API(this)
       signUpAPI.postCliente(client)
}
```

**API.kt:**

```
   fun postCliente(cliente: Cliente) {

        val TAG = "API Activity"
        val apiInterface: ApiInterface
        apiInterface = ClientApi.getClient().create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        val clientePostCall = apiInterface.postCliente(cliente)
        mProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        clientePostCall.enqueue(object: Callback<Cliente> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Cliente>, response: Response<Cliente>) {
                mProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"User " + response.body()!!.name + " created successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        val backHomeIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                        context.startActivity(backHomeIntent)
                    } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Problem is unknown: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }else {
                    try {
                        var jObjError = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                        var email = jObjError.getString("client_email")
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Email " + email + " já existe.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    } catch (e: IOException){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Problem is unknown: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Cliente>, t: Throwable) {
                mProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.localizedMessage)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Editing the EditText object in your api object would likely lead to issues, instead, when you do `signUpAPI.postCliente(client)` you should also pass something to listen for a callback and change your editText there, I can share a simple example if you need, RXJava/RXKotlin is usually a good solution for this. Also file names should be `CamelCased.kt`, mostly as per java and kotlin's conventions but it also might lead to issues with the compiler sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an enum which says which error ocurred like so:

```
enum class ApiError {
   EMAIL_EXISTS, UNKNOWN
}
```

Then your postClient function takes a function as parameter:

```
fun postClient(client: Client, errorCallback: (ApiError, String) -> Unit)
```

Once you reach any point of failure you can invoke this function like for example:

```
errorCallback(ApiError.EMAIL_EXISTS, "The email already exists")
```

and when you invoke the postClient function you do it like this:

```
postClient(client) { errorType, text ->
   if (errorType == ApiError.EMAIL_EXISTS) {
      emailErrorEditText.text = text
   }
}
```

If you have more cases its appropriate to use a [when statement](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression). The concept of having a function as a parameter falls into the scope of higher order functions. You can read more on them [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions-and-lambdas). They are really really useful.

Comment: It looks like a simple help, but you've no idea how I'm happy now! I worked perfectly, and the ENUM will help me to organize the code. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your kind response! If you have any further questions - just ask. And even though it sounds boring -> try to work your way through the kotlin documentation on kotlinlang.org. It will show you what is possible with the language :).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you shouldn't have code that accesses your views in the API callbacks to and to prevent those view references from keeping your Activity alive beyond it's intended lifecycle. You also want to keep your network code and view code cleanly decoupled.

What you can do is implement a ViewModel class with LiveData fields that hold the state of your UI (including errors). Then your Activity can observe these LiveData fields and do updates to the views. Within the ViewModel is also where you can have your API class do the actual API class whose callbacks will update the ViewModel's LiveData fields.

See this like from the Android docs for more info:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide